# How to override serif and sans-serif fonts separately in mac safari with custom style sheets?

Tags: css, macos, if-statement, fonts, safari

With the help of Google searching, I found out that you can override fonts in mac safari with custom style sheets using `!important`.
What I do not know is the method to override serif and sans-serif fonts separately.

I want to make a CSS-style sheet that goes something like this.

```
If font-family contains serif
  then Times New Roman !important
If font-family contains monospace
  then Operator Mono !important
Else Helvetica !important
```

Is this possible and how can you do it?

Comment: I assume you are referring to a user agent stylesheet. I'm not familiar with Safari. Can you not go into the browser settings and customize the fonts?